# R inconsistent results from readHTMLTable from XML package during web scraping

Tags: xml, r, parsing, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am have having an issue that is driving me crazy.

I am trying to read a directory structure, and it is providing inconsistent results.

Here is some code:

```
library(XML)

output <- readHTMLTable("http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/876603/")
output
```

If I execute this 10 times or so, I will get different results for "Last modified".

Here is the first couple rows of each output.

Case 1:

```
                               Name     Last modified Size             Description
1                              <NA>              <NA> <NA>                    <NA>
2                  Parent Directory                 Â    -                       Â
3                               00/ 02-Feb-2013 16:34    -                       Â
4          0000876603-00-000005.txt 15-Feb-2000 15:36 1.0M Document: Text Document
```

Case 2:

```
                               Name     Last modified Size             Description
1                              <NA>              <NA> <NA>                    <NA>
2                  Parent Directory                 Â    -                       Â
3                               00/ 09-Feb-2013 16:31    -                       Â
4          0000876603-00-000005.txt 15-Feb-2000 15:36 1.0M Document: Text Document
```

If you go to the website, you can tell that Case 2 is correct.

Does anyone know why this is giving me the inconsistent results?

Is there a solution?

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: After running many times, I am able to replicate your issue. `table(replicate(100, as.character(readHTMLTable("http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/876603/")[[1]][3, 3])))` gives roughly 50/50. Best guess is that the website/server is using a system of mirrors whose data are not in sync.

Comment: I was thinking that this might be the case, but I never run into it with the browser.  Is there anything on my end that can be done to try to get the results consistent?

Comment: Hmm, not sure. Can you explain why you are accessing the data more than once? And how often?

Comment: Well, I'm actually not trying to access it more than once.  I am just checking the code to make sure the results were right and came across the issue.  Ideally, I would only have to do it once.  Also, I think you reasoning was correct, because the SEC has an FTP mirror and I am getting the same effect there.

Comment: So if your only goal is to get reproducible results, you could use a modified version of `readHTMLTable` that caches its output. At the top of your script, define `library(memoise); my.readHTMLTable <- memoise(readHTMLTable)` and use that function instead.

Answer (score 0):

> So if your only goal is to get reproducible results, you could use a modified version of readHTMLTable that caches its output. At the top of your script, define

```
library(memoise); 
my.readHTMLTable <- memoise(readHTMLTable)
```

> and use that function instead.